Principal Value Integral Using Contour Integration
$$
\mbox{The Principal Value of}\quad
\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac 1{x(x^2+1)}dx=0
$$
since the integrand is an odd function.

In the complex plane, the integrand has simple poles at 0 (residue 1) at $i$ (residue -1/2) and at $-i$ (residue -1/2).
Integrating in the complex plane over a positively oriented semi circular contour of radius $R>0$ with an 'indentation' negatively oriented contour at 0 of radius $\epsilon>0$, by the 'Fractional Residue' Calculation
(Gamelin, Complex Analysis pg 209), letting $R\to\infty$ and $\epsilon\to 0$, the principal value is shown to be the product of $2\pi i$ with the sum of the residues in the open upper half plane plus the product of $-\pi i$ with the residue at 0.

By this, the principal value should be
$(2\pi i)(-1/2)+(-\pi i)1=-2\pi i\ne 0$.


On the other hand, if the semi-circular indented contour at 0 is taken in the positive direction, (as Boas, Invitation to Complex Analysis, Excercise 9.5 pg 74 asks you to do), the correct value 0 obtains.
So who is correct ?.


What do you mean "Who is correct?"  You (correctly) describe three different integrals.  They're all correct.

The statement about Gamelin is not correct. Take a look at the Theorem of Fractional Residues of Gamelin:

Theorem (Fractional Residue Theorem). If $z_0$ is a singular pole of $f(z)$ and $C_\epsilon$ is an arc of the circle $\left\{|z-z_0|=\epsilon\right\}$ of angle $\alpha$, then $$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \oint_{C_\epsilon} f(z) dz = \alpha i\operatorname{Res}(f(z),z_0)$$

However, note that Gamelin is assuming a positively oriented circle $z = z_0 + \epsilon e^{i\theta}, \; \theta_0 <\theta <\theta_0+\alpha$
In the proof he writes
$$ f(z) = \frac{A}{z-z_0} + g(z)$$
Where $A$ is the residue of $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ is analytic. This is a consequence of the Laurent series of $f(z)$.
Then,
$$\oint_{C_{\epsilon}} f(z)dz = \oint_{C_{\epsilon}} \frac{A}{z-z_0}dz + \underbrace{\oint_{C_{\epsilon}} g(z) dz}_{=0} = A\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_0+\alpha} \frac{i\epsilon e^{i\theta}d\theta}{z_0+\epsilon e^{i\theta}-z_0} = iA\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_0+\alpha} d\theta = i\alpha A$$
But what happen if the contour is negatively oriented, call it $C_{\epsilon^{-}}$?. Hence we have a circle $z=z_0 +\epsilon e^{-i\theta}, -\alpha+\theta_0<\theta <\theta_0$
and
$$\oint_{C_{\epsilon^{-}}} f(z)dz  = A\int_{-\alpha+\theta_0}^{\theta_0} \frac{-i\epsilon e^{-i\theta}d\theta}{z_0+\epsilon e^{-i\theta}-z_0} = -iA\int_{-\alpha+\theta_0}^{\theta_0} d\theta = -i\alpha A$$
In your example, as you put in the question the contour is the negatively oriented circle
$$ z = \epsilon e^{-i\theta}, \quad -\pi<\theta<0$$
Hence
$$\oint_{C_{\epsilon^{-}}} \frac{dz}{z(z^2+1)}  = -i\pi\operatorname{Res}(f(z),0) = -i\pi \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{1}{z^2+1} = -i\pi $$
So, the integral is also zero with the fractional residue of Gamelin.
